# Win32 API for Java with JNA: User32.INSTANCE.EnumChildWindows does not return anything

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I have the following code using JNA:

```
HWND foregroundWindow = Tools.getForegroundWindow();

    User32.INSTANCE.EnumChildWindows(foregroundWindow, new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {

        @Override
        public boolean callback(HWND hwnd, Pointer pntr) {
               
            char[] textBuffer = new char[512];
            char[] textBuffer2 = new char[512];
            User32.INSTANCE.GetClassName(hwnd, textBuffer, 512);
            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(hwnd, textBuffer2, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(textBuffer);
            String wText2 = Native.toString(textBuffer2);
            
            System.out.println("className: " + wText + " title: " + wText2);
            
            return true;
        }
        
    }, null);
```

The ones who are familiar with JNA implementation of win32 API should know that the purpose of this function is to return the child elements of a window.

When I start Mozilla Firefox.exe and press Ctrl+Shift+Delete a popup window opens for clearing the cache, cookies and history. I want to find the DELETE button so I can control it programmatically but the function above does not return any controls inside the window.

When I use a tool like inspec.exe it shows the child components.

So what am I doing wrong and how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the window handle stored in `foregroundWindow` to see that it really is the window you assumed it is?

Comment: Inspect.exe likely does not use `EnumChildWindows()`; Microsoft's accessibility APIs have methods for getting accessible children — **which does not necessarily map to window handles**. Firefox's children might not be actual windows; I don't personally know. Use Spy++ to find out about child window handles.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumChildWindows` enumerates the windowed child controls. Mozilla uses non-windowed controls.

You will need to use the automation API to have any chance of automating this.